# Issue with mhchem and fractions in make4ht and mathml

Tags: tex4ht, mhchem, make4ht, mathml

I am compiling a chemistry-heavy text and I noticed that mhchem on Overleaf did not create superscripts and subscripts when compiled with make4ht. Upon downloading the newest release, which put the support for make4ht back in, it compiled beautifully except for when using fraction bars.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

Text with formula \ce{CuCl2} and \ce{Cu^{2+}}.

\begin{equation}
\frac{\ce{mass CuCl2}}{1}\times\frac{\ce{1 mol CuCl2}}{\ce{MM of CuCl2}}= \mathord{?}\mathord{?}~\ce{ mol CuCl2}
\end{equation}

Text before a reaction.

\begin{equation}
\ce{Al^0 (s) -> Al^3+ (aq) + 3e-}\\
\ce{Cu^2+ (aq) + 2e- -> Cu^0 (s)}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

And I compile that using the following command:

```
make4ht -f html5 -e mybuild.mk4 -um draft -c mwe.cfg main "early^,early_"
```

Using this mwe.cfg file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml}

\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{%
     <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
       MathJax.Hub.Config({
         extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
         jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
         tex2jax: {
           \unexpanded{inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],}
           \unexpanded{displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],}
           processEscapes: true
         },
         "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
       });
     </script>
  }}

\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<script type="text/javascript"\Hnewline
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"\Hnewline
></script>\Hnewline}}

\Css{.MathJax_MathML {text-indent: 0;}}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The PDF renders fine, but the first equation renders in-line with no fractions.

Comment: 1. Combining MathJax with make4ht? I can learn a thing. But I cannot test here, at the moment. • 2. `\ce{mass CuCl2}` is not intended usage of mhchem. Might work but is not semantic. • 3. mhchem for LaTeX and mhchem for MathJax are not 100% equivalent. But what renders with LaTeX definitely also should render with MathJax. • 4. cdn.mathjax.org was switched off in more than 5 years ago. • 5. I wonder why wour .cfg file does not contain mhchem. • 5. Are you double-sure that the fractions render when there is no `\ce`?

Comment: @mhchem it seems that there is an error regarding Amsmath equations in TeX4ht, so this is why fractions don't work. The other issues are that HTML elements in `mhcem.4ht` are  hardcoded, which cause problems in math, when they are mixed with MathML code.

Comment: @michal.h21 I don't know too much about TeX4ht. Why would `\frac` be handled by TeX4ht? Is the above configuration not intended to use MathJax for math? Then `\ce` inside math should also be handled by MathJax, right? — For `\ce` inside text, the hard-coded HTML should be fine, I think.

Comment: @mhchem he is using MathML with MathJax (thanks to the `\Preamble{xhtml,mathml}` command in the config file). It works fine without MathML, with a simple configuration for the `\ce` command that keeps it's contents in the generated HTML.

Comment: @michal.h21 So, TeX4ht does all the parsing, creates MathML and MathJax is only used for display of the TeX4ht output? — Last time, I looked, TeX4ht wasn't very capable of parsing the math internally created by mhchem.sty. If it was, no mhchem.4ht would be needed.

Comment: @mhchem yes, in this case MathML is created by TeX4ht and MathJax is  used just for rendering. I think that the problem is related mainly to subscripts and superscripts, they need special handling due to catcode problems. Mhchem will be needed anyway, but it should be more general, as it should support both HTML  and MathML. I will try to do that.

Comment: @mhchem - yes, using \ce{mass CuCl2} is not what I tried first, but I saw in the a post somewhere that using \textrm{} along with math and mhchem might break things, so I tried to do something where I only used \ce{} or \text{}. Making it as minimal of an working example as possible.

Comment: @michal.h21 - surprisingly, without using the most up-to-date mhchem release, the fraction renders fine. But the subscripts/superscripts do not (apparently not going through mhchem). It was shocking to see a better fraction with one version of mhchem (not working) and then to see nice chemistry, but no fraction with the newer version of mhchem.

Comment: @mhchem - I copied most of my config file from elsewhere, so if there is a better way to include mhchem and mathjax, please do let me know. This is my first attempt at using make4ht/TeX4ht.

Comment: @mhchem I've updated my answer with an updated version of `mhchem.4ht`, with a basic MathML support. It doesn't support everything what the original does, as I don't know how to test features that are not included in this question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there is no MathML support for Mhchem at the moment, so you get this wrong rendering as a result. I will try to fix it, but until it is done, you can try the following configuration file. It uses built-in MathJax support in TeX4ht, and configures the `\ce` command to stay in the generated HTML, so it can be rendered by MathJax too:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathjax}
\def\ce#1{\texttt{\detokenize{\(\ce{#1}\)}}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This is the result:

[image]

Alternatively, here is a version of `mhchem.4ht` with basic MathML support:

```
%% mhchem.4ht
%% 2021-12-31
%% Copyright 2015-2021 Martin Hensel
%
%% This file is part of the mhchem bundle for LaTeX
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c
% which is included as lppl-1-3c.txt.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Martin Hensel.
%
% ( In order to fight spam, the maintainer's contact      )
% ( information is "encrypted" with ROT13.                )
% ( If you do not know ROT13 yet and have no tool for     )
% ( decryption, simply do an Internet search for "ROT13". )
%
% ,---[ ROT 13 ]---
% | Gur Pheerag Znvagnvare bs guvf jbex vf Znegva Urafry
% |   jub pna or pbagnpgrq ivn
% |     zupurz@ZnegvaUrafry.qr
% |   be ivn znvy
% |     Znegva Urafry
% |     Cbfgfge. 20
% |     09232 Unegznaafqbes
% |     Treznal
% `----------
%
% This work consists of all files listed in manifest.txt.
%
%
\ExplSyntaxOn

\Css
  { 
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-cf { white-space: nowrap; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-isotope { font-size: 0.65em; line-height: 1; display: inline-block; vertical-align: sub; text-align: right; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-supsub  { font-size: 0.65em; line-height: 1; display: inline-block; vertical-align: sub; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-sup     { font-size: 0.65em; line-height: 1; display: inline-block; vertical-align: 68\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-sub     { font-size: 0.65em; line-height: 1; display: inline-block; vertical-align: sub; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-rlap { display: inline-block; width: 0; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-bond-half-top    { vertical-align: 60\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-bond-half-middle { vertical-align: 35\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-bond-top         { vertical-align: 20\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-bond-bottom      { vertical-align: -20\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-arrow { display: inline-flex; flex-direction: column; vertical-align: middle; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-arrow > span { line-height: 80\%; text-align: center; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-arrow > .mhchem-above { min-height: 1em; font-size: 60\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-arrow > .mhchem-below { min-height: 1em; font-size: 60\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-arrow > span.mhchem-arrow-normal { line-height: 40\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-arrow > span.mhchem-arrow-larger { line-height: 25\%; font-size: 150\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-arrow > span.mhchem-arrow-complement { line-height: 25\%; }
  }

% basic mhchem containers
\NewConfigure{mhchemce}{2}
\NewConfigure{mhchemcf}{2}

\pend:def\__mhchem_output_begin_ce:{\a:mhchemce}
\append:def\__mhchem_output_end_ce:{\b:mhchemce}
\pend:def\__mhchem_output_begin_cf:{\a:mhchemcf}
\append:def\__mhchem_output_end_cf:{\b:mhchemcf}

\Configure{mhchemcf}{\HCode{<span~class="mhchem">}}{\HCode{</span>}}
\Configure{mhchemce}{\HCode{<span~class="mhchem">}}{\HCode{</span>}}


% alternative version of coreFivd

\NewConfigure{mhchemisotope}{3}
\Configure{mhchemisotope}{\HCode{<span~class="mhchem-isotope">}}{\HCode{<br~/>&\#xfeff;}}{\HCode{</span>}}

\NewConfigure{mhchemsub}{2}
\Configure{mhchemsub}{\HCode { <sub~class="mhchem-sub"> }}{\HCode { </sub> } }

\NewConfigure{mhchemsup}{2}
\Configure{mhchemsup}{\HCode { <sup~class="mhchem-sup"> }}{\HCode { </sup> } }

\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_coreFivefourht:nnnnnnn #1#2#3#4#5#6#7
  {
    \bool_if:nT
      { \tl_if_empty_p:n {#7}  &&  ! \tl_if_empty_p:n {#5} }
      { \bool_set_true:N \l__mhchem_option_superscriptsStacked_bool }
      
    \tl_if_empty:nF {#1#2} 
      {
        \a:mhchemisotope
        \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #1 } 
        \b:mhchemisotope
        \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #2 }
        \c:mhchemisotope
      }
    \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #3 } 
    \bool_if:NTF \l__mhchem_option_superscriptsStacked_bool
      {
        \tl_if_empty:nTF {#4#5#7} 
          {
            \tl_if_empty:nF {#6}
              {
                \a:mhchemsub
                \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #6 }
                \b:mhchemsub
              }
          }
          {
            \tl_if_empty:nTF {#6}
              {
                \a:mhchemsup
                \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #4#5#7 }
                \b:mhchemsup
              }
              { 
                \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-supsub"> }
                \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #4#5#7 }
                \HCode { <br~/>&\#xfeff; }
                \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #6 }
                \HCode { </span> } 
             }
          }
      }
      {
        \tl_if_empty:nF {#4}
          {
            \a:mhchemsup
            \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #4 }
            \b:mhchemsup
          }
        \tl_if_empty:nF {#6}
          { 
            \a:mhchemsub
            \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #6 }
            \b:mhchemsub
          }
        \tl_if_empty:nF {#5#7} 
          { 
            \a:mhchemsup
            \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #5#7 }
            \b:mhchemsup
          }
      }
  }

% replace original coreFive with our alternative version. it will work in picture math
\HLet\__mhchem_output_coreFive:nnnnnnn\__mhchem_output_coreFivefourht:nnnnnnn

\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_withFont:n #1  %. output #1 as math or text
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \l__mhchem_output_isMathMode_bool
      { \mathrm {#1} }
      { \text {#1} }
  }

\NewConfigure{mhchemoperator}{2}
\Configure{mhchemoperator}{\HCode { <span~class="mhchem-operator"> ~ }}{\HCode { ~ </span> }}

% ideally, these should be redefined using \HLet, to support picture math
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_skipAfterAmount: { \HCode { ~ } }  % space for copy & paste
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_skipBeforeStateOfAggregation: {}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_minus: { \HCode { &minus; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_operatorPlus:
  { \a:mhchemoperator + \b:mhchemoperator  }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_operatorMinus:
  { \a:mhchemoperator\HCode {&minus;} \b:mhchemoperator }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_operatorEquals:
  { \a:mhchemoperator =  \b:mhchemoperator }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_operatorPlusMinus:
  {\a:mhchemoperator \HCode {&plusmn; } \b:mhchemoperator }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_electronDot: { \HCode { &bull; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_additionCompound: { \HCode { &middot; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_excited: { \HCode { &\#x2731; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_commaDecimal: { , }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_commaEnumeration: { , \HCode { &thinsp; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_commaEnumerationSmall: { , \HCode { &thinsp; } }
  
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_single: { \HCode { &minus; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_double: { \HCode { &equals; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_triple: { \HCode { &equiv; } }
% todo: add MathML support for these
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_half:  % todo: improve
  { \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-bond-half-middle">&\#xfe4d;</span> } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_oneAndHalf:  % todo: improve 
  { \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-rlap">&minus;</span><span~class="mhchem-bond-half-top">&\#xfe4d;</span> } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_twoAndHalf:  % todo: improve
  { \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-rlap">=</span><span~class="mhchem-bond-half-top">&\#xfe4d;</span> } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_twoAndHalff:  % todo: improve
  { \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-rlap~mhchem-bond-top">&minus;</span><span~class="mhchem-rlap~mhchem-bond-bottom">&minus;</span><span~class="mhchem-bond-half-middle">&\#xfe4d;</span> } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_dotdotdot: { \HCode { &middot;&middot;&middot; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_dotdotdotdot: { \HCode { &middot;&middot;&middot;&middot; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_rightArrow: { \HCode { &\#xffeb; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_leftArrow: { \HCode { &\#xffe9; } }

\NewConfigure{mhchemarrow}{2}
\NewConfigure{mhchemarrowabove}{2}

\NewConfigure{mhchemarrowyields}{1}
\NewConfigure{mhchemarrowyieldsLeft}{1}
\NewConfigure{mhchemarrowyieldsLeftRight}{1}
\NewConfigure{mhchemarrowmesomerism}{1}
\NewConfigure{mhchemarrowequilibrium}{1}
\NewConfigure{mhchemarrowequilibriumRight}{1}
\NewConfigure{mhchemarrowequilibriumLeft}{1}

\Configure{mhchemarrow}{\HCode {<span~class="mhchem-arrow">}}{\HCode{</span>}}
\Configure{mhchemarrowabove}{\HCode { <span~class="mhchem-above">}}{\HCode{</span>}}
\Configure{mhchemarrowyields}{ \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-arrow-normal">&\#x27F6;</span> } }
\Configure{mhchemarrowyieldsLeft}{ \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-arrow-normal">&\#x2190;</span> } }
\Configure{mhchemarrowyieldsLeftRight}{ \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-arrow-normal">&\#x21c4;</span> } }  % todo: improve
\Configure{mhchemarrowmesomerism}{ \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-arrow-normal">&\#x2194;</span> } }  % todo: improve
\Configure{mhchemarrowequilibrium}{ \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-arrow-normal">&\#x21cc;</span> } }  % todo: improve
\Configure{mhchemarrowequilibriumRight}{ \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-arrow-larger">&\#x21c0;</span><span~class="mhchem-arrow-complement">&\#x21bd;</span> } }  % todo: improve
\Configure{mhchemarrowequilibriumLeft}{ \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-arrow-complement">&\#x21c0;</span><span~class="mhchem-arrow-larger">&\#x21bd;</span> } }  % todo: improve



\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_arrow_deployfourht:nnnnn #1#2#3#4#5
  {
    \a:mhchemarrow
    \tl_if_empty:nF {#3#5}
      {
        \a:mhchemarrowabove
        \str_case:nnF {#2}
          {
            {   } { \ce { #3 } }
            { M } { \ensuremath { #3 } }
            { T } { \text { #3 } }
            { C } { \ce { #3 } }
          }
          { \msg_error:nnn { mhchem } { unexpected-arrow-type } {#2} }
          \b:mhchemarrowabove
      }
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
      {
        { yields } {\a:mhchemarrowyields }
        { yieldsLeft } {\a:mhchemarrowyieldsLeft }
        { yieldsLeftRight } {\a:mhchemarrowyieldsLeftRight }  % todo: improve
        { esomerism } {\a:mhchemarrowesomerism }  % todo: improve
        { equilibrium } {\a:mhchemarrowequilibrium }  % todo: improve
        { equilibriumRight } {\a:mhchemarrowequilibriumRight }  % todo: improve
        { equilibriumLeft } {\a:mhchemarrowequilibriumLeft }  % todo: improve
      }
      { \msg_error:nnn { mhchem } { unexpected-arrow-type } {#1} }
    \tl_if_empty:nF {#3#5}
      {
        \a:mhchemarrowabove
        \str_case:nnF {#2}
          {
            {   } { \ce { #5 } }
            { M } { \ensuremath { #5 } }
            { T } { \text { #5 } }
            { C } { \ce { #5 } }
          }
          { \msg_error:nnn { mhchem } { unexpected-arrow-type } {#2} }
        \b:mhchemarrowabove
      }
    \b:mhchemarrow
  }

\HLet\__mhchem_arrow_deploy:nnnnn\__mhchem_arrow_deployfourht:nnnnn
  
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Additional configurations for MathML

% print mathml command or html, depending on if we are inside mathml or not
\newcommand\:mhmathmlorhtml[2]{\ifmathml\a:mathml #1\else #2\fi}
\newcommand\:mhonlyinmathml[1]{\ifmathml #1\fi}
\:CheckOption{mathml}
\if:Option

\Configure{mhchemcf}{\HCode{<\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}\space class="mhchem-cf">}}{\HCode{</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}>}}
\Configure{mhchemce}{\HCode{<\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}\space class="mhchem-ce">}}{\HCode{</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}>}}

\Configure{mhchemsub}{%
  \:mhmathmlorhtml{%
  \Send{BACK}%
  {<\a:mathml msub><\a:mathml mrow\Hnewline>}%
  \Tg</\a:mathml mrow>\Tg<\a:mathml mrow\Hnewline>\trap:base%
  }{%
  \HCode{<sub>}}%
}{\:mhmathmlorhtml{\Tg</\a:mathml mrow>\TG</\a:mathml msub\Hnewline>}{\HCode{</sub>}}}
\Configure{mhchemsup}{%
  \:mhmathmlorhtml{
  \Send{BACK}
  {<\a:mathml msup><\a:mathml mrow\Hnewline>}%
  \Tg</\a:mathml mrow>\Tg<\a:mathml mrow\Hnewline>\trap:base
  }{%
  \HCode{<sup>}}%
}{\:mhmathmlorhtml{\Tg</\a:mathml mrow>\TG</\a:mathml msup\Hnewline>}{\HCode{</sup>}}}

\Configure{mhchemoperator}{\HCode{<\:mhmathmlorhtml{mo}{span} class="mhchem-operator">}\PauseMathClass}{\EndPauseMathClass\HCode {</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mo}{span}>}}

\Configure{mhchemarrow}{\HCode {<\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}}}{\HCode{\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}>}}
\Configure{mhchemarrowabove}{\HCode { <\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-above">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}}}{\HCode{\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}>}}
\Configure{mhchemarrowyields}{ \HCode { <\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-normal">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x2192;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}> } }
\Configure{mhchemarrowyieldsLeft}{ \HCode { <\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-normal">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x2190;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}> } }
\Configure{mhchemarrowyieldsLeftRight}{ \HCode { <\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-normal">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x21c4;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}> } }  % todo: improve
\Configure{mhchemarrowmesomerism}{ \HCode { <\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-normal">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x2194;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}> } }  % todo: improve
\Configure{mhchemarrowequilibrium}{ \HCode { <\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-normal">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x21cc;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}> } }  % todo: improve
\Configure{mhchemarrowequilibriumRight}{ \HCode { <\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-larger">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x21c0;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}><\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-complement">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x21bd;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}> } }  % todo: improve
\Configure{mhchemarrowequilibriumLeft}{ \HCode { <\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-complement">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x21c0;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}><\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-larger">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x21bd;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}> } }  % todo: improve
\else
\fi
% }

\Hinput{mhchem}
```

The version of this file that is included in TeX Live mixes command redefinitions with the HTML code. It is better not to mix them but to use configurable hooks instead. In this way, you can support multiple output formats.

You can save this file to the same directory as your TeX file, it will be used automatically.

Here is a result with

```
 make4ht filename.tex "mathml,mathjax"
```

[image]

You need up-to-date version of TeX4ht, and development version of `make4ht` to get it work.

Comment: Is that the HTML output? That is what I get for the PDF, but the HTML just has "Undefined control sequence \ce" everywhere that the mhchem code would be. I'm using the exact mwe.tex I posted, with the config file you posted.

Comment: @JustinShorb yes, it is rendered HTML.

Comment: I will see what I can try within Overleaf. This does not render for me with the exact mwe.tex and the cfg file shown. You are compiling with the command I used above: make4ht -f html5 -e mybuild.mk4 -um draft -c mwe.cfg main "early^,early_" ?

Comment: @JustinShorb you don't need the `"early_,early^"` option in this case. But the problem can be caused by an older version of TeX4ht files on Overleaf.

Comment: @michal.h21 The header of the file (copyright information) needs an update to be correct (and to comply with the license). Please reach out to me via email, so we can discuss some more details.

Comment: @michal.h21 - if I have a follow-up on this with an issue that involves this same thing, but with using cleveref (or possibly) with using many \ce{} commands within an equation environment, should I ask a new question or pose it here?

Comment: @JustinShorb it is better to post a new question, it can get quite hard to follow when questions are heavily edited with non-related issues.

Comment: @michal.h21 - posted follow-up here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660453/using-mhchem-make4ht-and-cleverref-issues-with-equation-rendering

Comment: @michal.h21 Could you please reach out to me? Contact information at cover page of http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf (or the "encrypted" copyright header of mhchem.4ht

Comment: @mhchem sorry for the delay, I just sent you a mail