# Using mhchem, make4ht, and cleverref issues with equation rendering

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, tex4ht, mhchem, make4ht

This is a follow-up question to the one answered here: [Issue with mhchem and fractions in make4ht and mathml](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654236/issue-with-mhchem-and-fractions-in-make4ht-and-mathml).

Using that same MWE, but adding in hyperref, cleverref, and a label in the equation does not break the reaction (if using mhchem to build reaction equations-not shown here), but it does break the equation reference and destroys the equation rendering.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} % This makes references better
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

Text with formula \ce{CuCl2} and \ce{Cu^{2+}} referring to \ref{newLabel}.

\begin{equation}\label{newlabel}
\frac{\ce{mass CuCl2}}{1}\times\frac{\ce{1 mol CuCl2}}{\ce{MM of CuCl2}}= \mathord{?}\mathord{?}~\ce{ mol CuCl2}
\end{equation}

Text before a reaction.

\begin{equation}
\ce{Al^0 (s) -> Al^3+ (aq) + 3e-}\\
\ce{Cu^2+ (aq) + 2e- -> Cu^0 (s)}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

This uses the preamble config file from the other post: config.cfg

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathjax}
\def\ce#1{\texttt{\detokenize{\(\ce{#1}\)}}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

and it is run with the command:

```
make4ht -c config.cfg mwe.tex
```

Result:
[image: Screenshot showing a red snippet of LaTeX code with the begin equation and end equation visible with yellow highlight]

The HTML of the snippet using @michal.21 answer below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en' xml:lang='en'> 
<head> <title></title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<link href='mwe7.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
<meta content='mwe7.tex' name='src' /> 
<script>window.MathJax = { tex: { tags: "ams", }, }; </script> 
 <script async='async' id='MathJax-script' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js' type='text/javascript'></script>  
</head><body>
<!-- l. 11 --><p class='noindent'>Text with formula <span class='cmtt-10'>\(\ce {CuCl2}\) </span>and <span class='cmtt-10'>\(\ce {Cu^{2+}}\) </span>referring to
<span class='cmbx-10'>??</span>.
</p><!-- l. 15 --><p class='indent'>   \begin {equation} \@ifnextchar [\label@optarg \label@noarg {newlabel} \frac {\ce {mass CuCl2}}{1}\times \frac {\ce {1 mol CuCl2}}{\ce {MM of CuCl2}}= \mathord {?}\mathord {?}~\ce { mol CuCl2}  \end {equation} <a id='x1-2r1'></a>
</p><!-- l. 17 --><p class='indent'>   Text before a reaction.
</p><!-- l. 22 --><p class='indent'>   \begin {align}  \ce {Al^0 (s) -&gt; Al^3+ (aq) + 3e-}\\ \ce {Cu^2+ (aq) + 2e- -&gt; Cu^0 (s)}  \end {align}
</p>
    
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error that you get? Equation works for me, but the referencing doesn't as it needs to be handled by MathJax too. You can replace `\ref{newLabel}` by `$\eqref{newlabel}$`, and it should work.

Comment: @michal.h21 I have added what I get in my Chrome browser. there isn't an error in the terminal, but I can go find a more specific error in the log if you let me know where to look. I have a whole set of documents that all use \Cref{} for all references as I have multiple styles of tables, appendix tables, and the same for figures and equations. It would be very hard to retroactively try to force \ref to use all the custom names, I think.

Comment: Can you post your full config file? I don't get the MathJax error that you get. It shouldn't happen, as `\label` should be passed verbatim to the HTML file. Regarding `\cref` etc., it is quite complicated, as labels inside math are invisible on the LaTeX side. But I think that I found a solution some time ago using some Lua scripting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `\label` is inside the environment that is output verbatim to the HTML code, so LaTeX referencing system doesn't see it at all.

Fortunatelly, TeX4ht saves contents of the environment to a token list, and using LaTeX 3 regular expressions, we can search for `\label` and set it outside the verbatim block. Try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathjax}
\def\ce#1{\texttt{\detokenize{\(\ce{#1}\)}}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_extract_once:nnNTF {nV}
\AddToHook{env/equation/end}{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \regex_extract_once:nVNTF { label\s* \x{7B}([^\x{7D}]*)\x{7D}} {\l_tmpb_tl} \l_tmp_seq {\label{\seq_item:Nn\l_tmp_seq{2}}} {}
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

We execute the code that should searches for `\label` at the end of the `equation` environment, thanks to `\AddToHook{env/equation/end}`. We update manually the `equation` counter, because it is not done automatically in the MathJax mode. The `\label` is extracted using `\regex_extract_once:nVNTF` function. The `\l_tmpb_tl` is variable used by the MathJax node for some manipulations of the MathJax environment, so we can reuse it for our purposes. When it is found, we output `\label` in the true branch of the regex command.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: I use the same mwe.tex file at the top (edited because the document class was missing - maybe you did article?) and your config file and I get the same yellow box at the top, but now all of the text after the first reaction is missing. Your screenshot is also missing the second equation in the reaction scheme.

Comment: ah, I see the difference, now. You did have the second equation, but it's inline instead of a new line as the \\ would have expected.

Comment: @JustinShorb the second equation shows as one line even in the PDF mode, so I think you would need a different markup for two lines.

Comment: @JustinShorb there is also one issue with your sample, you need to use `\ref{newlabel}`, instead of `\ref{newLabel}`

Comment: Thanks, @michal.h21 That was definitely a typo. Still, using the mwe above (fixed to use newlabel properly), I still get the yellow rendering box without the equation. Within the yellow box is: \begin {equation} \@ifnextchar [\label@optarg \label@noarg {newlabel} \frac {\ce {mass CuCl2}}{1}\times \frac {\ce {1 mol CuCl2}}{\ce {MM of CuCl2}}= \mathord {?}\mathord {?}~\ce { mol CuCl2}  \end {equation}

Comment: @JustinShorb yes, it is really weird that you get this error. do you use up-to-date TeX Live? don't you have an older version of `mathjax-latex-4ht.4ht` file somewhere?

Comment: I just downloaded a fresh installation of TeX Live (MacTeX) on a new computer that I have done no work on. I used the exact file from the mwe posted here (with the \Cref spelling correction), your config file, and got the same yellow box. Maybe you have a different mathjax? Or were you using one from the other post?

Comment: @JustinShorb the strange thing is that you get the `\@ifnextchar... ` command in your  output, because everything that is inside `equation` should be passed verbatim to the HTML file. I don't know what can be the issue here, because I also tested it on multiple computers, and cannot reproduce it.

Comment: how many of the spaces in this line of your cfg file should be there, and should some be \\ instead? I'm trying to figure out why there are so many extra spaces in here and maybe it's a copy/paste issue in what is online:   \regex_extract_once:nVNTF { label\s* \x{7B}([^\x{7D}]*)\x{7D}} {\l_tmpb_tl} \l_tmp_seq {\label{\seq_item:Nn\l_tmp_seq{2}}} {}

Comment: @JustinShorb no, spaces seems OK. maybe post the generated HTML here?

Comment: Edited to add the output HTML.

Comment: @JustinShorb thanks. it is still mystery to me, how is this output even possible, as only `\label` is expanded in the equation and I don't see how is that even possible.

Comment: I updated this with a simpler question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661406/anything-inside-equation-with-ce-rending-mathjax-adds-extra-protect-for-mhchem I have tried this very very simple mwe and I still get extra text. Fresh installation of MacTeX. It can't even handle a % sign inside of the equation without adding something. I even re-typed every bit of the mwe in that post by hand, and the config file by hand. No copy/paste. @michal.h21